# Typescript compiler not using _this with lambda functions

Tags: typescript

I have two identical directives (apart from naming) and compiler creates a variable _this just fine in the other directive but not the other. And it may vary which one is fine and which one isn't. 
Both of them has a link function like this:

```
link = (scope: IMyScope, element, attrs) => {
    scope.setVariable1 = () => {
        this.service.setVariable1(scope.variable1);
    }
```

And a problem is when compiled version tries to use this.service(undefined) instead of _this.service.

Comment: which version of typescript do you use?

Comment: You see `this.service` in compiled file or it is just your guess? TypeScript keeps `this` in arrow functions only when target is `ES6`.

Comment: TypeScript 1.4 (updated it to 1.5 just yesterday). I see the compiled version of the service and ES6 is the target.

Comment: I resolved this by using controllers instead of link functions. It's not how I'd like it but I've spent far too much time trying to get link functions to function.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what might be the issue with your compilation but usually I don't declare directives as a class but as a function.

```
    function yourDirective(yourService): ng.IDirective{
         return {
              //other directive properties
              link: (scope: IMyScope, element, atrrs) =>{
                     scope.setVariable1 = () => {
                         yourService.setVariable1(scope.variable);
                     }
              }
         };
     };
     yourDirective.$inject = ["yourService"];

     angular.module("app").directive("yourDirective", yourDirective);
```

Then you don't need to use `this` in the link function.